# Group by weeks in Mongodb where dates are fixed (1-7, 8-14, 15-21, 22-28, 29-31)

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for a way to group my data which has a column with datetime in it.

I want to group it such that, the business requirement is to have the records by a fixed week definition of (1-7, 8-14, 15-21, 22-28, 29-31).

While MongoDB $week would group by calendar weeks.

Any idea how to go about this custom grouping?

Comment: See [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/)

Comment: Seems the right way to do it, but I am still a newbie to this, any links to a working example?